# Move minicart in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I am using a newheader.phtml file where I am calling mini cart inside li tag.

```
    <li>
<!--    <a href="cart.php"><img src='--><?php //echo $this->getViewFileUrl('img/cart_ic.png'); ?><!--'></a>-->
              <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('minicart') ?>
    </li>
```

In my default.xml file.

```
 <move element="minicart" destination="custom.header" />
        <referenceContainer name="header.container">
            <container name="custom.header" htmlClass="headerSection" htmlTag="div">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="header.sections" before="main.content" template="Magento_Theme::html/newheader.phtml">

                </block>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>
```

But when I see source code in browser changes will not reflect. I have already clear cache & deploy static content.

[image]

below is my custom header.

[image]

The last li tag is still blank, however, getchildhtml() has been called inside the custom header. But I need to display the cart icon inside the last li tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the minicart to your newly created block instead, change the xml:

```
<move element="minicart" destination="header.sections" />
```

Comment: I did this at first but did not get the expected output.